# Typescript - console.log doesn't show object properties

Tags: typescript

I am trying to iterate through an object properties, but I can't achieve it.

```
export class Test {
    public property1: string;
    public property2: number;

    test() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this));
    }
}

...

const t = new Test();
t.test();
```

The `console.log(this)` doesn't print any properties, therefore, the iteration on the line below returns an empty array.

Why ? (I have also tried with Object.keys(this))

Edit: the final goal is to do this:

```
export class MyObjectWithLessProperties {
    // lot of properties

    constructor(object: MyObjectWithMoreProperties) {
        Object.keys(this).forEach((key: string) => this[key] = object[key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized property values, so it is expected for them to be null.

This will work as expected:

```
class Test {
    public property1: string = "test";
    public property2: number = 123;

    test() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this));
    }
}

const a = new Test();
a.test();
```

Best way to go about this is to create a constructor for Test class, and when creating new Test() pass in the desired values as params

Example:

```
class Test {
    private property1: String;
    private property2: number;

    constructor(property1: String, property2: number) {
        this.property1 = property1;
        this.property2 = property2;
    }

    test() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this));
    }
}

const a = new Test("test", 123);
a.test();
```

Comment: But I don't want default values... I need to copy from an object passed in the constructor. Since I'm too lazy to copy them manually (they are a lot), I want to iterate through the object properties, and copy the value from the object in parameters.

Comment: please see the edited response with the example when using a constructor to instantiate a class

Comment: I have updated my question. The goal is to not have to do the mapping manually.

Comment: constructor(myObjectWithMoreProperties: object) {
        this.property1 = myObjectWithMoreProperties.getProperty1;
        this.property2 = myObjectWithMoreProperties.getProperty2;
        this.property3 = myObjectWithMoreProperties.getProperty3;

    }

you cannot iterate through properties of class that have not been initialized